# Why can't I see the ProgressDialog using this Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I can't make my ProgressDialog show up and I'm not sure why?

The Code:

```
public class Activity001 extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
     public void onClick(View view) 
     { 
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity001.this, "", "wait ", true, false);

                // Sending some files to server .. takes time .. -  (method that take 1-2 minutes ) 

    progressDialog.dismiss();

       } 
}
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: well you showing progress but ...you hide this as well, before async action is complited ... (you have problem with code flow?) ...in your sample code flow is: 1.show progress 2. **just start** async operation.. 3.hide progress...

Comment: No no .. sorry about the missunderstanding ... the 'sending some files' is some method that called and this method is take time - ( 1-2 minuts ) after this method is done - the code will dismiss the progressdialog.

Comment: this code will not work as well ... it will causing ANR ... use AsyncTask for this ... there are plenty example here or on google ... why it's not working ... you just block ui thread(onclick is called on ui thread) and ui messages(like fx. draw, other onclick, ontouch, etc) are not handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.,

Do this in your onCreate()

```
       Handler handler;
handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
     Pdialog.dismiss();     


     }
   };
```

And now use a thread to upload files to server. Modify this piece of code,

```
public class Activity001 extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
     public void onClick(View view) 
     { 
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity001.this, "", "wait ", true, false);
Thread ProgressThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                                // Sending some files to server .. take time .. -  (method that take 1-2 minuts ) 



                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    } finally {

                             handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                }
            };

                ProgressThread.start();


       } 

}
```

**EDIT**

Progress dialog is a light weight object. It does't take priority  over other tasks that happens in a main Thread. For example when you call a progress dialog's show() followed by a  http process  or something like that in the main thread, it will not allow the light weighted prgoress dialog to take priority. So obviously it will just show up at the end of the http process.

Comment: :You solved my problem too,actually i was unable to dismiss the progress dialog.but by putting dismiss in oncreate() solved my problem can you explain how it actually works?

Answer (score 2):

Instead this,  best method to implement Background task using Thread is [**`AsyncTask`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which is also known as [**`Painless Threading in Android`**](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

As this is known as painless threading, you don't need to take care about threading management.

As per your requirement, do as following:

1. Inside onPreExecute() method, show progress bar or progress dialog
2. Inside doInBackground() method, do your file sending tasks
3. Inside onPostExecute() method, implement dialog dismiss task.